# Regula Form Validation Crashes on validation

Tags: javascript, forms, playframework-2.0, regula

Im using this library for the first time, maybe Im making some stupid mistake but Im stuck.

I am using Play Framework 2.0 to serve regula 1.3.3 like this

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/regula-1.3.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then I have

```
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" data-constraints="@@Range(min=18, max=65)" />
```

Please Note that the @@ is required because of the Play Framework Template, however the Browser sees the same line like this:

```
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" data-constraints="@Range(min=18, max=65)">
```

and

```
    $(document.body).on('change','input', function (event) {
        var constraintViolations = regula.validate({
            elements: [document.getElementById("age")]
        });
    });
```

On the Console:

```
Uncaught IllegalArgumentException: No constraints have been bound to the specified elements: age. Function received: {elements: [[object HTMLInputElement]], elementIds: [age]}
```

If I add another element:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="@form("email").value" data-constraints='@@Email' >
```

and change the validation code to:

```
    $(document.body).on('change','input', function (event) {
        var constraintViolations = regula.validate({
            elements: [document.getElementById("age"), document.getElementById("email")]
        });
    });
```

I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
```

I also tried calling regula.validate() whenever a input field changes but this simple returns a empty array every time.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `regula.bind()` first? You have to call that so that regula can inspect all the elements and find out which ones have constraints on them. That is probably why it is complaining that no constraints have been bound on the element.